# Can not use cuDNN on context None: cannot compile with cuDNN: fatal error: cudnn.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, python-3.x, theano, theano.scan

I configured theano to be connected to the GPU and I installed all the required libraries.

I used the following code from the documentation to check if the GPU work:

```
THEANO_FLAGS='floatX=float32,device=cuda0,gpuarray.preallocate=1' python GPU.py
```

code:

```
from theano import function, config, shared, sandbox
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy
import time

vlen = 10 * 30 * 768  # 10 x #cores x # threads per core
iters = 1000

rng = numpy.random.RandomState(22)
x = shared(numpy.asarray(rng.rand(vlen), config.floatX))
f = function([], T.exp(x))
print(f.maker.fgraph.toposort())
t0 = time.time()
for i in xrange(iters):
    r = f()
t1 = time.time()
print("Looping %d times took %f seconds" % (iters, t1 - t0))
print("Result is %s" % (r,))
if numpy.any([isinstance(x.op, T.Elemwise) for x in f.maker.fgraph.toposort()]):
    print('Used the cpu')
else:
    print('Used the gpu')
# End gpu_test.py
```

but I got this error:

```
Can not use cuDNN on context None: cannot compile with cuDNN. We got this error:
b'/tmp/try_flags_47onlbh0.c:4:19: fatal error: cudnn.h: No such file or directory\ncompilation terminated.\n'
Preallocating 7554/7952 Mb (0.950000) on cuda0
Mapped name None to device cuda0: GeForce RTX 2080 (0000:17:00.0)
[GpuElemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<GpuArrayType<None>(float32, vector)>), HostFromGpu(gpuarray)(GpuElemwise{exp,no_inplace}.0)]
Looping 1000 times took 0.245761 seconds
Result is [ 1.23178029  1.61879349  1.52278066 ...,  2.20771813  2.29967761
  1.62323296]
Used the cpu
```

Any idea about the problem?

Comment: You have to install cuDNN, you have to install the development version of cuDNN, and it needs to be installed in a place that theano can find it.  You know that theano development stopped over a year ago, right?

Comment: I have to install it, or it has been stopped? my theano version is: `Theano==1.0.3+2.g3e47d39ac.dirty` and I'm using cuda-10.0

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you what is missing: `fatal error: cudnn.h: No such file or directory\ncompilation terminated`. It means that your cuda is not getting the cudnn.h file.

I faced the same problem and followed the following steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html#prerequisites-windows) for solving the problem. It worked!

> The following steps describe how to build a cuDNN dependent program.
>   In the following sections the CUDA v9.0 is used as example:
>
> Your CUDA directory path is referred to as `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA
>   GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0`
>
> Copy the following files of your downloaded cuDNN into the CUDA Toolkit directory.
>
> - Copy `yourinstallpath\cuda\bin\cudnn64_7.dll` to `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin`.
> - Copy `yourinstallpath\cuda\ include\cudnn.h` to `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\include`.
> - Copy `yourinstallpath\cuda\lib\x64\cudnn.lib` to `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\lib\x64`.
>
> Set the following environment variables to point to where cuDNN is
>   located. To access the value of the `CUDA_PATH` environment variable,
>   perform the following steps:
>
> Open a command prompt from the Start menu. Type Run and hit Enter.
>   Issue the control `sysdm.cpl` command. Select the Advanced tab at the
>   top of the window. Click Environment Variables at the bottom of the
>   window. Ensure the following values are set: Variable Name:
>   `CUDA_PATH`  Variable Value: `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0`
>
> Include `cudnn.lib` in your Visual Studio project. Open the Visual
>   Studio project and right-click on the project name. Click Linker >
>   Input > Additional Dependencies. Add `cudnn.lib` and click OK.